# Split single text column into two columns of all possible combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `cust_info` with columns `cust_id` and `cust_email`. Here the same customer can have multiple email IDs.

Now I am trying for a query where each `cust_id` must be mapped to two different combinations of email. The order does not matter.

My Input table:

```
cust_id   cust_email
1001      sample1001_1@email.com
1001      sample1001_2@email.com
1001      sample1001_3@email.com
1001      sample1001_4@email.com
1002      sample1002_1@email.com
1002      sample1002_2@email.com
1002      sample1002_3@email.com
```

Expected Output:

```
cust_id  cust_email_1            cust_email_2
1001     sample1001_1@email.com  sample1001_2@email.com
1001     sample1001_1@email.com  sample1001_3@email.com
1001     sample1001_1@email.com  sample1001_4@email.com
1001     sample1001_2@email.com  sample1001_3@email.com
1001     sample1001_2@email.com  sample1001_4@email.com
1001     sample1001_3@email.com  sample1001_4@email.com
1002     sample1002_2@email.com  sample1002_1@email.com
1002     sample1002_2@email.com  sample1002_3@email.com
1002     sample1002_3@email.com  sample1002_1@email.com
```

I tried using inner join:

```
SELECT c1.cust_id, c1.cust_email, c2.cust_email
FROM cust_info c1
INNER JOIN cust_info c2
    ON  c1.cust_id = c2.cust_id AND c1.cust_email != c2.cust_email;
```

But for above-tried query, I am getting permutations instead of combinations that I don't need.
For example:

```
1001    sample1001_1@email.com  sample1001_2@email.com
1001    sample1001_2@email.com  sample1001_1@email.com
```

I already explored a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845149/sql-all-combinations-of-dates-from-a-single-column-into-two-columns) but since that query uses a date column, a comparison operator was used for filtering permutation. But in my case, the column is a string.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What are you *actually* using?

Comment: my bad, I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your join condition to use an `<` inequality:

```
SELECT
    c1.cust_id,
    c1.cust_email,
    c2.cust_email
FROM cust_info c1
INNER JOIN cust_info c2
    ON c1.cust_id = c2.cust_id AND
       c1.cust_email < c2.cust_email;
```

This should prevent the sort of duplicate pairs you are currently seeing.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I didn't know that comparison operators can be used with string columns in SQL. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators/26081086)